# Display images in inline carousel not working

Tags: javascript, blueimp, instafeedjs

I am trying to make a gallery for my [personal website](https://codophobia.github.io/). The problem is that the the gallery doesn't show up in a carousel but instead shows like a grid gallery. I have followed everything from the official [setup](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#carousel-setup) guide. When I inspect the [page](https://codophobia.github.io/), I get something like this written in console:

```
blueimp Gallery: No or empty list provided as first argument. HTMLCollection[18]
```

gallery code:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
 <div id="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '',
        accessToken: '',
        clientId: '',
        template: {% raw %}'<a href = {{image}}  ><img src = "{{image}}"></a>'{% endraw %},
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        limit: 18,
        links: false
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script>
blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('instafeed').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
        carousel: true
    }
);
</script>
```

{% raw %} is used since the site is being made in jekyll. I read about it [here](http://matthewelsom.com/blog/display-instagram-photos-on-webpage-with-instafeed.html).
The image gallery can be found on the bottom of my [personal site](https://codophobia.github.io/).

Updated code:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
 </div>
 <div id = "instafeed">
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '270912755',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        accessToken: '270912755.4e019ce.38f9a6730d14410b919b96cc3ee658dd',
        clientId: '4e019ce8ec2744dca631db3ddf85607d',
        template: {% raw %}'<a href = "{{image}}" ><img src = "{{image}}"></a>'{% endraw %},
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        limit: 18,
        links: false,
        mock: true,
        success: function(response) {
            blueimp.Gallery(
            document.getElementById('instafeed').getElementsByTagName('a'),
            {       container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
                    carousel: true
            }
            );
        }
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mouser You meant the exclusion of double quotes for {{image}}?

Comment: No the `{%raw %}` before the opening quote and after the closing quote. That will throw an error. In your code on the page it's deleted.

Comment: What is use of {% raw %} and {% endraw %}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should solve your timing problem:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '',
    accessToken: '',
    clientId: '',
    template: '{% raw %}<a href = {{image}}  ><img src = "{{image}}"></a>{% endraw %}',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: 18,
    links: false,
    after: startCarousel
});
feed.run();

function startCarousel()
{
  blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('instafeed').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
        carousel: true
    }
  );
}
```

I've wrapped the Carousel code into a function that gets called back by the *Instafeed*  code with the option `after`. That should start the Carousel after the images from *Instagram*  are loaded.

> Advanced Options (from the Instafeed [Github](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js))
>
> - before  (function) - A callback function called before fetching images from Instagram.
>
>   - after  (function) - A callback function called when images have been added to the page.
>   - success  (function) - A callback function called when Instagram returns valid data. (argument -> json object)
>   - error  (function) - A callback function called when there is an error fetching images. (argument -> string message)
>   - mock  (bool) - Set to true fetch data without inserting images into DOM. Use with success callback.
>   - filter  (function) - A function used to exclude images from your results. The function will be given the image data as an argument, and expects the function to return a boolean. See the example below for more information.

Comment: delayed by few secs, our answer are exactly same.

Comment: @AnilKumar, yup great minds..., yours still has the `{% raw %}` outside of the quotes and will throw an error ;-)

Comment: One more problem. I now get the carousel gallery but then grid gallery also appears at the bottom.

Comment: @ShivamMitra, look at the documentation. There is a mock function, you can use with the success option. Turn mock on, then feed the dom list into the gallery code with the success option.

Comment: Can you please give an example for it?

Comment: @Mouser Can you please look at my updated code at bottom? Now the carousel gallery is not appearing.

Comment: @ShivamMitra, thanks for using SO. But the convention is that you open a new question, since you former problem has been resolved.

Comment: @ShivamMitra, quick solution, replace `document.getElementById('instafeed').getElementsByTagName('a')` with the `response` argument. Should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132201/discussion-between-shivam-mitra-and-mouser).

Answer (score 1):

Call the blueimp.Gallery in after call function of inst feed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '',
        accessToken: '',
        clientId: '',
        template: {% raw %}'<a href = {{image}}  ><img src = "{{image}}"></a>'{% endraw %},
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        limit: 18,
        links: false,
 after: function () {    
               blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('instafeed').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
        carousel: true
    }
);
            },
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('instafeed').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
        carousel: true
    }
 );
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: document.ready could help here, but it's not the solution to the problem, it neither help the OP to understand the timing issue. The instafeedjs code provides a callback on the code.